# PostgreSQL constraint - only one row can have flag set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  actual boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

How can I set a constraint that only one row can have `actual` flag set to `TRUE`?

Comment: Advice: false takes one byte, NULL doesn't cost anything. And when all records have the same value, except one, NULL might be the better (and cheaper) solution.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can create a unique [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) on that column only for true values:

```
create unique index on my_table (actual) 
where actual = true;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91f62/1

Comment: Should it be `actual is true`?

Comment: @FrozenFlame: no, `actual = true` is perfectly fine. In fact, `where actual` would be enough.

Comment: Working dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4592

Answer (score 11):

My approach would add another feature to an index-based only solution: automatic deactivation of the current flag when setting the flag on another row.

That would involve, of course a trigger.

I would also recommand, as suggested by Frank Heikens, storing "not actual" state as a `null` instead of `false`. In postgresql, each `null` value is different from another `null` value, so the unicity constraint is quite easy to solve: we can allow for only one `true` value, and as many `null` value as necessary.

Here is my implementation:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  actual boolean,
  CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT actual_not_false CHECK(actual != false)
);
```

.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_table USING btree(actual nulls LAST);
```

.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ensure_only_one_enabled_state_trigger()
 RETURNS trigger
AS $function$
BEGIN
    -- nothing to do if updating the row currently enabled
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.actual = true) THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    -- disable the currently enabled row
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I.%I SET actual = null WHERE actual = true;', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME);

    -- enable new row
    NEW.actual := true;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

.

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_only_one_enabled_state
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF actual ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.actual = true)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ensure_only_one_enabled_state_trigger();
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! Is it good practice to use `null` instead of `false` though? Now, Im considering to use the CHECK `(column != false)` in all of my tables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

This should be doable with an exclusion constraint. For your case:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name text,
    actual boolean DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    EXCLUDE (actual WITH =) WHERE (actual)
);
```

Tested with:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'something', false);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'something_else', true);
```

Then the following is a constraint violation

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'third_thing', true);
```