# Rails active record unique constraints with field value on postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is it possible to create unique constraints on active record with value of field.

So this code will add a constraints of 2 columns:

```
add_index :my_table,[:field_1,:field_2],:unique => true
```

But I would like to have the same constrains where field_2 == true

For example something like this

```
add_index :my_table,[:field_1,:field_2 => true],:unique => true
```

Is it possible ? 
I saw that it is possible on [postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166915/postgresql-constraint-only-one-row-can-have-flag-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For partial indexes you can use the `where` option:

```
add_index :my_table, [:field_1, :field_2], unique: true, where: 'field_2 = true'
# "index_my_tables_on_field_1_and_field_2" UNIQUE, btree (field_1, field_2) WHERE field_2 = true
```