# Prisma: make boolean so only one can be true at the same time

Tags: typescript, boolean, prisma

Is it possible to make a boolean "unique" in Prisma? I want only one row to be 'true' at the same time. @Unique doesn't work because there can be multiple 'false'.

I know there are better options to keep track of whether someone is logged in, but according to the assignment I MUST do it this way....

[Screenshot of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqabc.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What...? If a boolean is unique then there can only be two possible values...

Comment: @catgirlkelly That's the problem, I want it so there van be multiple false, but only one tree...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index with a custom migration:

```
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only --name init
```

[PostgreSQL constraint - only one row can have flag set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166915/postgresql-constraint-only-one-row-can-have-flag-set)

```sql
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Entity" (
    "id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "value" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Entity_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on "Entity" ("value") 
WHERE "value" = true;
```